# libreOffice, is automation possible to delete empty table rows?

Tags: libreoffice

I have a mail merge generated document which comprises repeats of a template with a fixed number of table rows in.

In some of the repeats few of the rows are used.

Is there a way to delete all empty rows across all tables in the document en masse?

TIA